# cloudbees and compojure database connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, clojure, postgresql-9.1, cloudbees, compojure

I've been playing around a bit with compojure and cloudbees. so far so good. but to do anything meaningful I need to connect the application (made using the Clickstart) to a database (or vice versa depending on how you look at it). This is the documentation available on the site for using their DBaaS option:

```
To register this database as a datasource in your application, insert the following XML snippets into your application configuration files.

WEB-INF/cloudbees-web.xml

<resource name="jdbc/landlords" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
 <param name="username" value="db-name" />
 <param name="password" value="db-pasword" />
 <param name="url" value="jdbc:cloudbees://landlords" />
</resource>

WEB-INF/web.xml

<resource-ref>
 <res-ref-name>jdbc/landlords</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

forgive me but I don't see where the WEB-INF directory is (or any *web.xml file). The only thing close is config.xml ( i can post the contents but so far i don't think it's the same).

specifically i'm trying to use this: http://www.enterprisedb.com/cloud-database/amzn-launch-guide-dbaas

Answer (score 0):

documentation is for JavaEE applications. For other stacks, you should use [datasource binding](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Resource+Management). I can't tell exactly how to configure the compojure config as I don't know anything about this stack